# Replacing broken capacitors with ones that have bigger capacitance

Tags: power-supply

I have a Samsung 205BW screen, and over the time, the capacitors on the power board broke down. I have to wait up to 30 mins for them to warm up so I can use the screen. I bought replacement capacitors according to the youtube video [how to replace samsung 205bw capacitors](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pMNNcdYrSZU):

- 4 x 1000uf 35v
- 1 x 470uf 63v

But after I opened up the board, the capacitors I had installed were:

- 5 x 820uf 25v
- 1 x 330uf 25v

I also [took pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKt7o.jpg).

Is there a way to replace the broken capacitors with whatever I have?

Comment: Please capitalize "I" when referring to yourself. It is not relevant to the question what you are willing to pay nor how long you are willing (or unwilling) to wait. I have edited your question accordingly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it'll work as you want - there's a seriously good chance it won't hurt anything. After all 5 x 820uF (4100uF) is only a bit bigger than 4 x 1000uF.

The 470uF being a bit bigger than the 330uF shouldn't really be a problem. These won't be timing capacitors and if they are only on internal DC power lines going a bit bigger or a tad smaller shouldn't cause problems.

It's worth a shot.

Comment: I will change the group of 4 in the right down corner as it is the source of the squeal. Wish me good luck.

Comment: I will certainly wish you luck though I have doubts that this mod will need it. I do hope this is the actual problem though and this solves it. I've got a power up delay problem on one of my studio monitors and it takes 15 minutes to settle - a right royal pain in the a*s it is!!

Answer (score 1):

There *are* cases where increasing a capacitance can be a problem, but they're rare. Timing caps are one, but electrolytics aren't generally used for that. Electrolytic caps are not precise critters. Their actual capacitance when new is often 50% higher than nominal, to account for degradation over time.

Another case where increasing capacitance could be a problem is if the caps are on the output of a switching regulator. Many switching regulators have a "maximum output capacitance" spec, and exceeding that can cause incorrect operation. However, in your specific case, the changes you're making are pretty small, as Andy points out. It really shouldn't matter if the circuit is designed with any overhead at all on the max load capacitance. Still, something to keep in mind if it doesn't work when you're done.