# Capacitor replacement - different uF value

Tags: power-supply, capacitor, components, monitor

Nice to see strackexchange has an electrical site too.
I am not familiar with electrical components and this is a kind of "low level hardware" if I can say it this way.

My monitor's matrix stopped working. With an eye shot I see the monitor itself is working, but the matrix didn't turn on.

After some research I found the problem - It has 3 capacitors on the power supply board which are not looking so good.

I have bought 3 capacitors with the same size and voltage - but the uF value is a little different

Broken capacitors: 820uF - 25V - 105.C max temp
New capacitors: 1000uF - 25V -105 .C max temp

I know that this kind of capacitors can be replaced with other capacitors with almost the same uF value (+/- 20%). But in my case they are 3 (not just one).

I am thinking about replacing them, but I have to know:
Is there a chance to make critical damage to the power board due to the capacitor's uF values?
Can u hint me about what can happen?

Comment: The only thing to be sure of is the physical dimensions, do they actually fit and won't they touch anything that the original caps didn't touch either (eg when they're heiger). Other than that you have a *good chance* that they'll work if the voltage rating is at least equal or better. No guarantees.

Comment: duplicate too: [Replacing broken capacitors with ones that have bigger capacitance](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/99806/7036)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Electrolytic capacitors have a *very* large value tolerance, -30/+50 % is not uncommon, so your small in crease in capacity is unlikely to cause a problem. And you have matched the temperature rating too, good.

But there is one other parameter that can be crucial in your case (presumably a switching power supply): the series resistance. If this value is too high, your new capacitors will not last long. Unfortunatly this value is not show on the component. If the original ones have a brand and type number you might be able to google the value.